# Translation of Cabeo's Philosophia magnetica

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, charge, history

Is there a translation of [Niccolò Cabeo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niccol%C3%B2_Cabeo)'s work *Philosophia magnetica* into English (or other modern language)? The original text in Latin is available for example [here](https://preserver.beic.it/delivery/DeliveryManagerServlet?dps_pid=IE7320178) but I can't find any translation (unlike William Gilbert's *De Magnete* for example).

Comment: you should ask this question at the https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ (History of Science and Mathematics)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I've asked there: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15782/translation-of-cabeos-philosophia-magnetica